# Examples of pytest-qgis github pipeline?

Tags: qgis, github, testing

I just found `pytest-qgis`, I added a few tests locally, working nicely!

I'm just curious has anyone used it in a Github Pipeline, to test a QGIS plugin?

When I try to run it I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'` ( https://github.com/axelande/geodatafarm3/actions/runs/7406364727/job/20150674470 ) does anyone know if https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/.docker could be used in an action

Answer (score 1):

I found this project:
https://github.com/GispoCoding/qaava-qgis-plugin/tree/master

After some trail and error I got it working on my repo as well (https://github.com/axelande/geodatafarm3/blob/try_ci/.github/workflows/python-app.yml), so now it gets tested on the latest qgis build every week or when I push code to the repo :)